# Installing imagemagick perlmagick on Windows Strawberry Perl

Tags: perl, imagemagick, cpan, strawberry-perl, perlmagick

Has anyone had any success recently installing imagemagick/perlmagick on Windows with recent versions of strawberry perl? I have read and tried many of the things suggested that I found online however none is very recent and none has worked for me. I've added all the imagemagick folders to the path as well. Seems there is a problem with finding the right files with imagemagick install. I have tried adding directories to the make file but still always errors out with

```
 Magick.xs:60:10: fatal error: magick/MagickCore.h: No such file or directory
 #include <magick/MagickCore.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Versions: perl 5.30.2x64-multi-thread, ImageMagick-7.0.10-31-Q8-x64-dll, Windows server 2019. Any help or direction here is appreciated.

Comment: The message indicates that compilation process is require `MagickCore.h` file. You need source code of the imagemagic to be available for compilation process.

Comment: @PolarBear indeed, I had install this package in ubuntu, must have imagemagick install first.

Comment: @Han.Oliver - OP does not specify what OS he works with. In your case as you use Linux you need `[package]-dev` be installed - development package includes required header files.

Comment: Yes I specified windows server 19 with strawberry perl

Comment: Tried, and can reproduce. Even when checking the box to install `convert`. Busy now. Will look at it in ~5 hours, or maybe tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have installed ImageMagic v7, which is not backwards compatible with v6. The Image::Magick on CPAN requires [ImageMagick v6](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/).

(That said, I got test failures when trying to install Image::Magick with the latest binary of v6. [I'm not the only one.](https://www.cpantesters.org/distro/P/PerlMagick.html?oncpan=1&distmat=1&version=6.89-1&grade=3))

Comment: Yes me too. Thanks for your help. I will look at for solutions other than imagemagick

Comment: Or use the command line tools rather than the library